# Is the fiber product of the connected component of a group scheme connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, group-schemes

Let $G$ be a group scheme over a field $k$. Let $G^0$ be the connected component containing the identity. Is it true that $G^0\times_k G^0$ is connected? 
I know that this is true if $G^0$ is geometrically connected, but how to prove it in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some outside help I figured out the answer to the question. Actually everything needed was here http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/download/varieties.pdf. 
Since the identity is a $k$-rational point contained in $G^0$ and this one is connected, we can apply **Lemma 5.14**. Then $G^0$ is geometrically connected, this allows us to conclude using **Lemma 5.4**.

Comment: Instead of the pdf download, could you maybe give us the Tag number of the Lemma. This is the best way to cite the stacks project. If you give me a pdf link then any updated version of it will have another numbering arrangement of the Lemmas, Propoisition etc. and saying Lemma 5.14 would not help anymore. Whilst the Tag number does not change with different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Since the numberings in Stacks Project have been updated, for convenience, I rewrite the argument here.

To show that $G^0\times_k G^0$ is connected, by [EGAIV$_2$, 4.5.8], it suffices to show that $G^0$ is geometrically connected.
Since $G^0_k$ is connected by definition, and contains a $k$-rational point (which is the neutral section), we apply

**[EGAIV$_2$, 4.5.14]** Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $k$. If there is a point $x\in X$ such that $\kappa (x)$ is a primary extension of $k$ (for instance, $x$ is a $k$**-rational point** of $X$), then the connected component of $X$ containing $x$ is geometrically connected.

In conclusion, for every group scheme $G$ over a field $k$, the neutral component $G^0$ is geometrically connected and $G^0\times_k G^0$ is connected.